# Segmentation fault when publishing to a topic while the ModelPlugin which subscribes to this topic is deleted

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using two gazebo plugins, `VictimPlugin` and `LifeBuoyPlugin`. The `VictimPlugin` subscribes to a topic to get a bool that is used by `timerThreadFunction`, which sleeps for a predefined amount of time and when it awakes if this bool is `true` it deletes the gazebo model associated to the plugin. The `LifeBuoyPlugin` publishes this bool which indicates if the model should be deleted or not.

The problem is that sometimes when `LifeBuoyPlugin` is trying to publish and `VictimPlugin` is deleted a segmentation fault happens, the gdb log is:

```
#0  0x00007ffff5dbcfa0 in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x110) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:65
#1  0x00007fffbc942fa0 in ros::Publication::hasSubscribers() () at /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007fffbc933296 in ros::TopicManager::publish(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::function<ros::SerializedMessage ()> const&, ros::SerializedMessage&) () at /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffeb85d92e5 in void ros::Publisher::publish<std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> > >(std_msgs::Bool_<std::allocator<void> > const&) const ()
    at /home/gus/Documents/git/jason_ros_ws/devel/lib/liblifebuoy.so
#4  0x00007ffeb85d653c in gazebo::LifeBuoyPlugin::OnRosMsg(boost::shared_ptr<gazebo_msgs::ModelStates_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) () at /home/gus/Documents/git/jason_ros_ws/devel/lib/liblifebuoy.so
```

`VictimPlugin` code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>

#include <gazebo/transport/Node.hh>
#include <gazebo/common/Plugin.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/Model.hh>
#include <ignition/math/Pose3.hh>

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Bool.h"
#include "ros/callback_queue.h"
#include "ros/subscribe_options.h"

namespace gazebo{
  class VictimPlugin : public ModelPlugin{
  private:
    gazebo::transport::NodePtr node;
    std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;

    ros::Subscriber rosSub;
    ros::CallbackQueue rosQueue;
    std::thread rosQueueThread;

    bool drowning = true;

    physics::ModelPtr model;

    int drowning_time_ = 0;
    std::thread timer_thread_;
    std::mutex mtx;

    void timerThreadFunction(){
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(
        std::chrono::milliseconds(this->drowning_time_));

      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);

      if(this->drowning){
        gazebo::transport::PublisherPtr request_pub = this->node->Advertise<msgs::Request>("~/request");
        msgs::Request *msg = msgs::CreateRequest("entity_delete", this->model->GetName());
        request_pub->Publish(*msg);
        delete msg;
      }
    }

    void QueueThread(){
      static const double timeout = 0.01;
      while (this->rosNode->ok())
      {
        this->rosQueue.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
      }
    }

  public:
    VictimPlugin() : ModelPlugin(){}
    ~VictimPlugin(){
      rosQueue.clear();
      rosQueue.disable();
      rosNode->shutdown();
      rosQueueThread.join();
      timer_thread_.join();
    }

    void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf){
      model = _model;

      this->node = boost::make_shared<gazebo::transport::Node>();
      this->node->Init();

      if (!_sdf->HasElement("drowningTime")){
        this->drowning_time_ = 5000;
        ROS_DEBUG("Victim plugin missing <drowningTime>, default to 5000ms");
      }else{
        this->drowning_time_ = _sdf->Get<int>("drowningTime");
      }

      if (!ros::isInitialized()){
        ROS_FATAL_STREAM("A ROS node for Gazebo has not been initialized, unable to load plugin. "
          << "Load the Gazebo system plugin 'libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so' in the gazebo_ros package)");
        return;
      }
      this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle("victim"));

      ros::SubscribeOptions so =
        ros::SubscribeOptions::create<std_msgs::Bool>(
          "/victim/"+this->model->GetName(),
          1,
          boost::bind(&VictimPlugin::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
          ros::VoidPtr(), &this->rosQueue);

      this->rosSub = this->rosNode->subscribe(so);

      this->rosQueueThread =
        std::thread(std::bind(&VictimPlugin::QueueThread, this));

      this->timer_thread_ =
        std::thread(std::bind(&VictimPlugin::timerThreadFunction, this));
    }

    void OnRosMsg(const std_msgs::BoolConstPtr &_msg){
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtx);
      this->drowning = _msg->data;
    }
  };
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(VictimPlugin)
}
```

`LifeBuoyPlugin` code:

```
#include <gazebo/common/Plugin.hh>
#include <gazebo/physics/physics.hh>
#include <thread>
#include <ignition/math/Pose3.hh>
#include "gazebo/common/common.hh"
#include "gazebo/gazebo.hh"

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "ros/callback_queue.h"
#include "ros/subscribe_options.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/ModelStates.h"
#include "gazebo_msgs/DeleteModel.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Pose.h"
// #include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "std_msgs/Bool.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

double euclideanDistance(geometry_msgs::Pose &buoyPose, ignition::math::Pose3d &modelPose){
  return  pow(pow(buoyPose.position.x - modelPose.Pos().X(), 2) +
              pow(buoyPose.position.y - modelPose.Pos().Y(), 2) +
              pow(buoyPose.position.z - modelPose.Pos().Z(), 2), 0.5);
}

namespace gazebo{
  class LifeBuoyPlugin : public ModelPlugin{
  private:
    physics::ModelPtr model;

    std::unique_ptr<ros::NodeHandle> rosNode;

    ros::Subscriber rosSub;
    ros::CallbackQueue rosQueue;
    std::thread rosQueueThread;

    void QueueThread(){
      static const double timeout = 0.01;
      while (this->rosNode->ok())
      {
        this->rosQueue.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
      }
    }

  public:
    LifeBuoyPlugin() : ModelPlugin(){}

    ~LifeBuoyPlugin(){
      rosQueue.clear();
      rosQueue.disable();
      rosNode->shutdown();                     // This MUST BE CALLED before thread join()!!
      rosQueueThread.join();
    }

    void Load(physics::ModelPtr _model, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf){
      model = _model;

      if (!ros::isInitialized()){
        ROS_FATAL_STREAM("A ROS node for Gazebo has not been initialized, unable to load plugin. "
          << "Load the Gazebo system plugin 'libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so' in the gazebo_ros package)");
        return;
      }
      this->rosNode.reset(new ros::NodeHandle("buoy"));

      ros::SubscribeOptions so =
        ros::SubscribeOptions::create<gazebo_msgs::ModelStates>(
          "/gazebo/model_states",
          1,
          boost::bind(&LifeBuoyPlugin::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
          ros::VoidPtr(), &this->rosQueue);

      this->rosSub = this->rosNode->subscribe(so);

      this->rosQueueThread =
        std::thread(std::bind(&LifeBuoyPlugin::QueueThread, this));
    }

    void OnRosMsg(const gazebo_msgs::ModelStatesConstPtr &_msg){
      for (size_t i = 0; i < _msg->name.size(); i++) {
        if(_msg->name.at(i).compare(0, 6,"victim") == 0){
          geometry_msgs::Pose victimPose = _msg->pose.at(i);
          ignition::math::Pose3d buoyPose = model->WorldPose();

          double distance = euclideanDistance(victimPose, buoyPose);
          if(distance < 2.5 & ros::ok()){
            std_msgs::Bool pubMsg;
            pubMsg.data = false;

            ros::Publisher victimPub;
            victimPub = rosNode->advertise<std_msgs::Bool>("/victim/"+_msg->name.at(i), 1);
            victimPub.publish(pubMsg);

            i = _msg->name.size();
          }
        }
      }
    }

  };
  GZ_REGISTER_MODEL_PLUGIN(LifeBuoyPlugin)
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25527/segmentation-fault-when-publishing-to-a-topic-while-the-modelplugin-which-subscribes-to-this-topic-is-deleted/) by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Setting `so.transport_hints = ros::TransportHints().unreliable();` solved this

```
ros::SubscribeOptions so =
        ros::SubscribeOptions::create<std_msgs::Bool>(
          "/victim/"+this->model->GetName(),
          1,
          boost::bind(&VictimPlugin::OnRosMsg, this, _1),
          ros::VoidPtr(), &this->rosQueue);

      so.transport_hints = ros::TransportHints().unreliable();
```

---

Originally posted by [rezenders](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26928/rezenders/) with karma: 5 on 2020-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0